# Using MOXy JAXB and not displaying list element node

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a class that generated the standard XML using JAXB. I need the XML changed a bit to make the list node not appear and the content of the list to appear directly under the list containing node.

```
package forum11919522;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Person {

    private Property property;

    public Property getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(Property property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public static class Property {
        private String type;
        private String location;
        private List<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        /** getter setter omitted **/

    }

    public static class Vehicle {
        private String vin;
        private int year;
        /** getter setter omitted **/
    }

}
```

Current xml:

```
<person>
    <property>
        <type>personal</type>
        <location>abc</location>
        <vehicle>
            <vin>2532</vin>
            <year>2012</year>
        </vehicle>
        <vehicle>
            <vin>125321</vin>
            <year>2010</year>
        </vehicle>
    </property>
</person>
```

desired:

```
<person>
    <property>
        <type>personal</type>
        <location>abc</location>
        <vin>2532</vin>
        <year>2012</year>
        <vin>125321</vin>
        <year>2010</year>
    </property>
</person>
```

Is it possible to do with MOXy?

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the `vehicle` element?  It makes it much harder for anyone to process vehicles as a list (I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead).

Comment: Yes. Just wondering if it is possible to do it that way. I know I can use the XmlPath if it was a vehicle object instead of list. When I use list, XmlPath(".") gets translated to <.> in the generated xml using MOXy.